# deploying laravel 7 project to hostinger

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

We have registered account for `hostinger` and uploaded the Laravel 7 projects into the server and followed the steps from the following [URL](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323/). But our projects are under the domains folder and as follows in the below picture

[image]

When accessing the `URL`, the default route is working but the other pages are not working and show error as the page is lost. Please suggest to us the right way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is this related to cPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably due to rewrites rules are not enabled.
Is there any .htaccess in your public folder ? Maybe try to add the correct laravel 7 .htaccess with the needed rewrites rules.

public_html/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```